# Network timeout in Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Node Admin SDK.

We have a few Firebase Cloud Functions that are sometimes heavily triggered from document writes to Firestore.

These functions run bulk writes and transactions that occasionally time out on the network call, always at 60 seconds after the `runTransaction()`  or the `bulkWritter.flush()` is called.

Just to clarify:

- I'm NOT talking about the Firebase Functions timeout (which can be set up to 540 seconds for gen1 functions)
- I'm NOT talking about contention retries on transactions, which can be set with `runTransaction(..., { maxAttempts })`.
- I'm talking about what seems to be a **network** timeout on these Firestore calls.

I'm just guessing our Firestore instance is so heavily loaded that it just takes a lot of time to reply.

For example, bulk writes throw with `4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline exceeded     at BulkWriterOperation.onError (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/bulk-writer.js:96:37)`

I can't find any argument to set a network call timeout, or something similar. Does anyone have any suggestions?

I understand the proper solution would be to implement a retry wrapper or something, but I'm not supposed to make any heavy changes to this production service in the next few weeks. I'm just looking for a quick, harmless patch, in case anyone knows.

Thanks in advance :+1:

**EDIT:**

That `4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED` from bulk writes was just an example. I'm also experiencing `3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid transaction` after 60 seconds as well, but for transactions instead of bulk writes. Of course, the transaction arguments are fine. It just hangs for 60 seconds, then it throws (similar to bulk writes but with a different error).

I'm already carefully handling many considerations regarding hotspotting, using small bulk size of 100 operations, small sized documents, ramp up is supposed to be handled by Firestore libs, and many other considerations as explained by the documentation and best practice recommendations.

But sometimes traffic just spikes and I'm guessing we're hitting [this idle timeout of 60 seconds](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#writes_and_transactions):

> Time limit for a transaction: 270 seconds, with a 60-second idle expiration time.

Both errors trigger after hanging for 60 seconds (transactions are not retrying because of contention, they're just hanging, then throwing). That's why I consider this is not exactly the same case as many other questions asking about `DEADLINE_EXCEEDED` or `INVALID_ARGUMENT` independently. It looks as an idle timeout error.

Is there a way to change the **idle timeout** in a transaction call?

Comment: I'm marking this as a duplicate because Firestore's "DEADLINE_EXCEEDED" has already been discussed at length here on SO.  Since you're not sharing your code or saying exactly what or how much you are writing, it's not really possible for us to give actionable advice.  You are almost certainly just exceeding a Firestore limit (or making a programming error), and there no simple patches, workarounds, or configurations for that in a general sense.

Comment: Many thanks @DougStevenson. I just edited and added more information considering it may not be exactly the same case. Thx

Comment: You have to retry any DEADLINE_EXCEEDED errors or anything related to limits or invalid arguments.  There is no configuration to change any of that behavior in Firestore.  The error is on the server, not the SDK, and the SDK does not retry errors conditions related to load.

Comment: Server error, you're right @DougStevenson , thank you for your help. I'll end up doing that retry wrapper I wanted to avoid for the next few days  xD